# Force browser to immediately repaint a dom element

Tags: javascript, css, browser, repaint, reflow

I need to insert a huge html markup to some dom element which will take awhile. It is a reason why I want to display some preloader indicator. I have two blocks: #preloader and #container. Some code displays the preloader firstly and then starts to paste a big html markup.

The problem - preloader hasn't really displayed until browser will not finish render html markup. I've tried a lot of solutions (a lot of them are described [here](http://www.eccesignum.org/blog/solving-display-refreshredrawrepaint-issues-in-webkit-browsers)) but still haven't success.

An example is avalable below:
https://jsfiddle.net/f9f5atzu/

```
<div id='preloader'>Preloader...</div>
<div id='container'>Container...</div>

#preloader {
  display: none;
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  hight: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

#container {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


setTimeout(function() {
  // Define variables
  let domPreloader = document.getElementById('preloader');
  let domContainer = document.getElementById('container');
  const html = Array(100000).fill("<div>1</div>");

  // Display preloader
  domPreloader.style.display = 'hide';
  domPreloader.offsetHeight;
  domPreloader.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(1)';
  domPreloader.style.display = 'block';

  // Render a big html
  domContainer.innerHTML = html;
}, 1000);
```

Is there any solutions for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The way you did it, you're not releasing control to the browser between the display of the preloader and the display of the 'big html'.

Rather than encapsulating this whole block inside a `setTimeout()`, you should just differ the rendering part.

Please try something along those lines:

```
// Define variables
let domPreloader = document.getElementById('preloader');
let domContainer = document.getElementById('container');

// Display preloader
domPreloader.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(1)';
domPreloader.style.display = 'block';

// Render a big html
setTimeout(render, 100);

function render() {
  const html = Array(100000).fill("<div>1</div>");
  domContainer.innerHTML = html;

  // Hide preloader
  domPreloader.style.display = 'none';
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Arnauld/guppbn6f/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've hoped there is some way to control painting during the same execution stack.

Comment: Is it possible that browser doesn't stop animation in some block (via backgroud-image css property or css animation) during rendering of some other block?

Comment: If the rendering operation is very CPU intensive, any animation would probably be at least jerky, if not completely frozen. The solution is to divide your operation in smaller ones (e.g. 100 x `html = Array(1000).fill("<div>1</div>");` in your example) and use a `setTimeout()` to launch the next batch.